# x64 nasm: pushing memory addresses onto the stack & call function

Tags: macos, gcc, assembly, x86-64, nasm

I'm pretty new to x64-assembly on the Mac, so I'm getting confused porting some 32-bit code in 64-bit.
The program should simply print out a message via the `printf` function from the C standart library.
I've started with this code:

```
section .data
    msg db 'This is a test', 10, 0    ; something stupid here

section .text
    global _main
    extern _printf

_main:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp       

    push    msg
    call    _printf

    mov     rsp, rbp
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

Compiling it with nasm this way:

```
$ nasm -f macho64 main.s
```

Returned following error:

```
main.s:12: error: Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses
```

I've tried to fix that problem byte changing the code to this:

```
section .data
    msg db 'This is a test', 10, 0    ; something stupid here

section .text
    global _main
    extern _printf

_main:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp       

    mov     rax, msg    ; shouldn't rax now contain the address of msg?
    push    rax         ; push the address
    call    _printf

    mov     rsp, rbp
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

It compiled fine with the `nasm` command above but now there is a warning while compiling the object file with `gcc` to actual program:

```
$ gcc main.o
ld: warning: PIE disabled. Absolute addressing (perhaps -mdynamic-no-pic) not
allowed in code signed PIE, but used in _main from main.o. To fix this warning,
don't compile with -mdynamic-no-pic or link with -Wl,-no_pie
```

Since it's a warning not an error I've executed the `a.out` file:

```
$ ./a.out
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Hope anyone knows what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 64-bit OS X ABI complies at large to the [System V ABI - AMD64 Architecture Processor Supplement](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf). Its code model is very similar to the *Small position independent code model (PIC)* with the differences explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/MachOTopics/1-Articles/x86_64_code.html). In that code model all local and small data is accessed directly using RIP-relative addressing. As noted in the comments by Z boson, the image base for 64-bit Mach-O executables is beyond the first 4 GiB of the virtual address space, therefore `push msg` is not only an invalid way to put the address of `msg` on the stack, but it is also an impossible one since `PUSH` does not support 64-bit immediate values. The code should rather look similar to:

```
   ; this is what you *would* do for later args on the stack
lea   rax, [rel msg]  ; RIP-relative addressing
push  rax
```

---

But in that particular case one needs not push the value on the stack at all. **The 64-bit calling convention mandates that the fist 6 integer/pointer arguments are passed in registers** `RDI`, `RSI`, `RDX`, `RCX`, `R8`, and `R9`, exactly in that order. The first 8 floating-point or vector arguments go into `XMM0`, `XMM1`, ..., `XMM7`. Only after all the available registers are used or there are arguments that cannot fit in any of those registers (e.g. a 80-bit `long double` value) the stack is used. 64-bit immediate pushes are performed using `MOV` (the `QWORD` variant) and not `PUSH`. Simple return values are passed back in the `RAX` register. The caller must also provide stack space for the callee to save some of the registers.

`printf` is a special function because it takes variable number of arguments. When calling such functions `AL` (the low byte of RAX) should be set to the number of floating-point arguments, passed in the vector registers. Also note that `RIP`-relative addressing is preferred for data that lies within 2 GiB of the code.

Here is how `gcc` translates `printf("This is a test\n");` into assembly on OS X:

```
    xorl    %eax, %eax             # (1)
    leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rdi     # (2)
    callq   _printf                # (3)

L_.str:
    .asciz   "This is a test\n"
```

(this is AT&T style assembly, source is left, destination is right, register names are prefixed with `%`, data width is encoded as a suffix to the instruction name)

At `(1)` zero is put into `AL` (by zeroing the whole RAX which avoids partial-register delays) since no floating-point arguments are being passed. At `(2)` the address of the string is loaded in `RDI`. Note how the value is actually an offset from the current value of `RIP`. Since the assembler doesn't know what this value would be, it puts a relocation request in the object file. The linker then sees the relocation and puts the correct value at link time.

I am not a NASM guru, but I think the following code should do it:

```
default rel             ; make [rel msg] the default for [msg]
section .data
    msg:  db 'This is a test', 10, 0    ; something stupid here

section .text
    global _main
    extern _printf

_main:
    push    rbp                 ; re-aligns the stack by 16 before call
    mov     rbp, rsp       

    xor     eax, eax            ; al = 0 FP args in XMM regs
    lea     rdi, [rel msg]
    call    _printf

    mov     rsp, rbp
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

Comment: Should the function remove the parameters from the stack or should the caller remove them? (if there are any parameters on the stack)

Comment: The caller should clean up the stack after the invocation.

Comment: Your answer does not really explain why NASM won't create the object file. The reason is a limitation of Mac OS X. The image base is larger than 2^32 on OS X. The OP's original code will assemble fine with elf64. [mach-o-64-bit-format-does-not-support-32-bit-absolute-addresses-nasm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26394359/mach-o-64-bit-format-does-not-support-32-bit-absolute-addresses-nasm/26402647#26402647)

Comment: @Zboson, hm, that Mach-O 64-bit does not support 32-bit absolute addresses is evident from the error message in the question, therefore I've probably considered it unnecessary to explain the problem further (or I was simply being lazy after a day at work - more likely) and have given directly the solution. My statement about the conformance to the SysV AMD64 ABI is not entirely correct though. I will expand the paragraph and add the corresponding references.

Comment: @HristoIliev, I deleted my answer on the other question. Your answer and mine make this question complete now so the other question is now a duplicate.

Comment: BTW, [`xor eax,eax` is the most efficient way to zero AL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and).  And BTW, closed [Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses. NASM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26402647) as a dup of this; thanks @ZBoson

Answer (score 5):

No answer yet has explained why NASM reports

```
Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses
```

The reason NASM won't do this is explained in [Agner Fog's Optimizing Assembly](http://agner.org/optimize/optimizing_assembly.pdf) manual in section *3.3 Addressing modes* under the subsection titled *32-bit absolute addressing in 64 bit mode* he writes

> 32-bit absolute addresses cannot be used in Mac OS X, where addresses are above 2^32 by
>   default.

This is not a problem on Linux or Windows. In fact I already showed this works at [static-linkage-with-glibc-without-calling-main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26358119/static-linkage-with-glibc-without-calling-main). That hello world code uses 32-bit absolute addressing with elf64 and runs fine.

@HristoIliev suggested using rip relative addressing but did not explain that 32-bit absolute addressing in Linux would work as well. In fact if you change `lea     rdi, [rel msg]` to `lea     rdi, [msg]` it assembles and runs fine with `nasm -efl64` but fails with `nasm -macho64`

Like this:

```
section .data
    msg db 'This is a test', 10, 0    ; something stupid here

section .text
    global _main
    extern _printf

_main:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp       

    xor     al, al
    lea     rdi, [msg]
    call    _printf

    mov     rsp, rbp
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

You can check that this is an absolute 32-bit address and not rip relative with `objdump`. However, it's important to point out that the preferred method is still rip relative addressing. Agner in the same manual writes:

> There is absolutely no reason to use absolute addresses for simple memory operands. Rip-
>   relative addresses make instructions shorter, they eliminate the need for relocation at load
>   time, and they are safe to use in all systems.

So when would use use 32-bit absolute addresses in 64-bit mode? Static arrays is a good candidate. See the following subsection *Addressing static arrays in 64 bit mode*. The simple case would be e.g:

```
mov eax, [A+rcx*4]
```

where A is the absolute 32-bit address of the static array. This works fine with Linux but once again you can't do this with Mac OS X because the image base is larger than 2^32 by default. To to this on Mac OS X see example 3.11c and 3.11d in Agner's manual. In example 3.11c you could do

```
mov eax, [(imagerel A) + rbx + rcx*4]
```

Where you use the extern reference from Mach O `__mh_execute_header` to get the image base. In example 3.11c you use rip relative addressing and load the address like this

```
lea rbx, [rel A]; rel tells nasm to do [rip + A]
mov eax, [rbx + 4*rcx] ; A[i]
```

Comment: I simply cannot find a reliable information as to why 64-bit Mach-O binaries have their image base so high, but it seems that on x86-64 `__PAGEZERO` segment occupies the whole first 4 GiB of the VM and thus any 32-bit pointer is invalid (`__PAGEZERO` is neither readable nor writeable or executable). It's probably a cheap way to detect old program code that assumes `sizeof(int)` to be equal to `sizeof(void *)` by simply crashing the program.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23188634/1374437) and the comment to it indicate that my assumption is probably correct.

Comment: @HristoIliev, It looks like you figure it you out. I'm wondering what other effect this has. It means that the addressing mode [absolute 32-bit address + index] for static arrays is not possible with OS X. Evgeny Kluev's suggestion to my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25899395/obtaining-peak-bandwidth-on-haswell-in-the-l1-cache-only-getting-62 would be impossible with OS X. Some instructions/ports (e.g. port 7 on Haswell) only work with this simple addressing mode. Also micro-op fusion might be effected http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046634/micro-fusion-and-addressing-modes

Comment: If you're going to use 32-bit absolute addressing for putting static addresses in registers, use `mov edi, msg` like Linux `gcc -fno-pie` will.  *That's* a more widespread use of 32-bit absolute addressing than indexing static arrays.  (Although it only saves code size, not instructions.  But `mov reg,imm32` can run on more ports than LEA.)

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation for the x86 64bit instruction set http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/325383.pdf

PUSH only accepts 8, 16 and 32bit immediate values (64bit registers and register addressed memory blocks are allowed though).

```
PUSH msg
```

Where msg is a 64bit immediate address will not compile as you found out.

---

What calling convention is _printf defined as in your 64bit library?

Is it expecting the parameter on the stack or using a fast-call convention where the parameters on in registers? Because x86-64 makes more general purpose registers available the fast-call convention is used more often.

Comment: `msg` is a 32-bit address so the problem is not `PUSH`. The problem is that Mach-O does not allow 32-bit absolute addressing.