# OSX ld: why does pagezero_size default to 4GB on 64b OSX?

Tags: macos, x86-64, ld

This is an OSX linker question. I don't think OSX (BSD or Mach layers) cares how large the zero page is or indeed whether it even exists. I think this is a tools thing. But that's my opinion and that's why I'm asking.

*-pagezero_size size: By default the linker creates an unreadable segment starting at address zero named __PAGEZERO.  Its existence will cause a bus error if a NULL pointer is dereferenced.*

This is clear; it's for trapping NULL ptrs. On a 32b OSX system, the size of the segment is 4KB which is the system pagesize. But on current 64b system, the size of this segment increases to 4GB. Why doesn't it remain at the system pagesize 4KB or the architecture's maximum pagesize, 2MB? This means I can't use 32b absolute addressing at all.

Are there any problems with using this flag and overriding the default? Apple Store rules, ...?

(This feature is specific to the OSX ld64 linker. The feature dates at least to ld64-47.2 March 2006. Address Space Layout Randomization and 64b support start with Leopard in October 2007.)

Comment: I'm going to guess, having looked over x86_64 addressing modes, that this doesn't 'cost' anything since the addressing modes don't really support short addresses. At the same time, if you forbid the lower 4GB of addressing then you force programs to be 64b clean. However, this is an OSX thing and GNU ld doesn't do this and doesn't provide this switch.

Comment: The code in ld64/Options.cpp says: case CPU_TYPE_ARM64:
   case CPU_TYPE_X86_64:
    // first 4GB for x86_64 on all OS's
    fZeroPageSize = 0x100000000ULL;
    break; So it's 4GB for x86_64 and ARMv8 but doesn't say why.

Comment: A trivial hello world program compiled+linked with "cc -pagezero_size=0x1000 test.c" dies immediately with "Killed: 9". Looking at the a.out with "otool -l a.out|more" it is missing a __PAGEZERO section. Same result with "cc -pagezero_size=0x0000000100000000 test.c". So you can't trivially set the PAGEZERO size to 4096.

Comment: "This means I can't use 32b absolute addressing at all" - which is a good thing, because the macho64 file format simply doesn't support it. Even if you changed the flag, the assembler is not going to let you generate a macho64 object file containing 32 bit absolute addressing. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091987/x64-nasm-pushing-memory-addresses-onto-the-stack-call-function) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23188378/mach-header-64bit-and-pagezero-segment-64bit/23188634#23188634). The purpose seems to be to invalidate all 32 bit pointers, which has advantages.

Comment: Thanks but I was going to mmap() a page to the low 4GB and then use normal 64b register addressing. I had a good reason for this. Yeah, I do think that Apple is trying to invalidate all 32b points for 64b cleanliness reasons as well as ASLR. And yep, I don't think there's any way of getting around this.

Comment: Does Apple sell any hardware using Silvermont?  And can you use OS X on/with Knight's Landing (Xeon Phi)?  If so, then keep in mind that branches across a 4GB boundary are predicted less well than normal branches on those low-power architectures.  (e.g. indirect `call` to a shared library mapped very far away).  See Intel's optimization manual, section 15.3.1.2 (silvermont) and 16.2.5.2
Branching Across 4GB Boundary (Knight's Landing).  Intel recommends using `LD_PREFER_MAP_32BIT_EXEC` on Linux to prefer mapping all code in the low 32, but any other 4GB block is also fine.

Comment: Other than that, you're correct that there's no perf downside to avoiding the low 32 bits of virtual address space if all your code is PIC anyway (which is the case on OS X).  Otherwise you miss out on `mov edi, imm32` to put a pointer in RDI for static data.

Comment: `PAGEZERO` segment with non-zero size is obligatory in `x86-64` , it's not in 32bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-pagezero_size` option is a linker option, not a compiler option. So, when you use the compiler to drive linking, you need to pass it as `-Wl,-pagezero_size,0x1000` (or whatever size you want). This works fine. The Wine project, to which I'm a contributor, relies on this for compatibility of its 64-bit build.

My understanding as to why the default page-zero size is 4GB for 64-bit is to catch cases where a pointer was inadvertently stored in a 32-bit variable and thus truncated. When it's eventually cast back to a pointer, it will be in the low 4GB and therefore invalid. Any attempt to dereference it will cause an access violation.

Update:

It seems that `-pagezero_size` is recognized as a compiler option, too, and works just fine in my testing. Either way, I get a functioning executable and `otool` shows a `__PAGEZERO` segment of the desired size.

What versions of the tools are you using? I'm using Xcode 8 on Sierra (10.12.6):

```
$ cc --version
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.41)
...
```

Comment: Command line clang. Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38) which should be latest+greatest. Thanks. This works for me. It makes sense that Wine uses this and it's good to know I'm in well trodden territory because I thought I wasn't.