# Static linkage with glibc without calling main

Tags: gcc, assembly, nasm, glibc

I have created a simple hello world using NASM which calls `printf` and `_exit` from libc but does not use `main`.

```
extern printf
extern _exit

section .data
    hello:     db 'Hello world!',10

section .text
    global _start   
_start:
    xor eax, eax
    mov edi, hello
    call printf
    mov rax, 0    
    jmp _exit
```

I create the object file like this

```
nasm -felf64 hello.asm
```

Then I can link it using dynamic linkage with glibc like this

```
ld hello.o -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -lc -melf_x86_64
```

This runs correctly with no errors. But now I want to do it statically.  I do

```
ln -s `gcc -print-file-name=libc.a`
ln -s `gcc -print-file-name=libgcc_eh.a`
ld hello.o -static libc.a libgcc_eh.a libc.a -melf_x86_64
```

This links but when I run the code I get a segmentation fault. Using `gdb` I see it gives

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000401004 in vfprintf ()
```

If I write a simple hello world in C and compile with static in runs fine so apparently it's possible to link statically to glibc on my system. **How can I use static linkage with glibc with my assembly code?**

If I link to an alternative to glibc such as [musl-libc](http://www.musl-libc.org/) it works fine

```
ld hello.o -static /usr/local/musl/lib/libc.a -melf_x86_64
```

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, eglibc 2.19, and GCC 4.9.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Glibc have a huge initialization sequence, because it is done with strong intention to work in multithreading systems. Also GLIBC properly handles some GNU extensions like constructor attributes. On startup, it caching a lot inside TLS, including locale information, it initializes synchronization objects and so on.

Exact problem with your vprintf is uninitialized locale access.

When you are linking to it dynamically, all this work is done on loading and everything works.

Statically linked glibc requires `__libc_init_first` to be called to initialize all it need. Before this call you need `__dl_tls_setup` to properly setup TLS and after this call you will need `__libc_csu_init` to properly call all global constructors.

All this stuff is highly version-dependent and practically undocumented. Strictly saying, there is no safe way to link statically to glibc, skipping or modifying its normal `_start` sequence.

On the other hand, embedded-oriented libraries like musl or newlib are not so restrictive about initialization and multithreading and locales.

Comment: Thank you, this is a better answer than I expected. It's time I throw in the towel and accept that linking statically to glibc should be avoided.