# Compile C random function in assembly

Tags: assembly, random, linker, nasm

Can anyone please guide me on how to compile assembly code with using c function?I used rand() function.When i compile programme it says me undefined function.i use these commands for compile 
 *nasm -f elf hello.asm*

*ld -m elf _i386 -s -o hello hello.o*

Can anyone please tell me how to compile my assembly programme with rand () function?

Comment: Try `ld hello.o -o hello -dynamic-linker  /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -lc -melf_i386`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using rand for x86_64 using the System V AMD64 calling conventions:

```
;rand.asm
extern printf
extern rand
extern _exit

section .data
    hello:     db 'rand %d',10

section .text
    global _start   
_start:
    xor eax, eax
    call rand
    mov esi, eax
    mov edi, hello
    xor eax, eax
    call printf
    mov rax, 0    
    jmp _exit
```

Compile and link like this

```
nasm -felf64 rand.asm
ld rand.o -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -lc -melf_x86_64
```

This produces the same result as

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int x = rand();
    printf("rand %d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

but without using main.

So for 32-bit code (the code above is only for x86_64) you would do

```
ld rand.o -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -lc -melf_i386
```

Comment: It's not quite the same, is it? The C code will run through a lot of C-library initialization before `main()`, the asm starts at `_start:` with no initialization.

Comment: @EOF, I'm not sure what you mean by the "the same". It produces the same output. All the C-library initialization is taken care of by the dynamic library as far as I understand. [If this was static linking it would be another story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26358119/static-linkage-with-glibc-without-calling-main). Maybe that's what you're thinking of?

Comment: Well, if you run `objdump` on the compiled C executable, you can see a lot of initialization being done before `main()` is even called. This is not a knock against your answer, just something to keep in mind.

Comment: @EOF, well the OP did not say if he was calling main. I think it's fair to assume he's not since he's trying to link directly rather than let GCC do it. But with I compile the C code (call it foo.c) with `GCC -O3 -S -masm=intel foo.c` and look at foo.s  I don't see a lot of initialization being done. In fact the only extra code is really some stack alignment (sub rsb, 8 at the start and add rsb,8 at then end).

Comment: Well, try `objdump -d [executable]`. Really. `gcc -S` does **not** show you all the auto-generated init code your ELF contains.

Comment: @EOF, okay, I see your point. I normally look at the `objdump -d` on the object file not the executable.

Comment: @EOF, yeah `objdump -d` on the executable only using `start` and the one using `main` are quite different.

Answer (score 0):

Link and initialize the appropriate library. One can often glean the needed linker commands by compiling a C example with high verbosity.