# How to call c functions that call c standard library in nasm?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, nasm, ld

First I want to clarify that I know this question might have been answered hundreds of times. However after hours of Google search I simply couldn't find anything that's exactly what I want. Also even though I've been writing c programs for quite a while, I'm kind of new to nasm and ld. So I would really appreciate it if I can get a simple answer without having to read a whole  nasm/ld tutorial or the complete manual.

What I want to do is:
say I have a function written in c that calls some function in the c standard library:

```
/* foo.c */
#include <stdio.h>
void foo(int i)
{
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

I want to call this function in nasm so I tried this:

```
; main.asm
global _start
extern foo

section .text
_start:
    push 1234567
    call foo
    add esp, 4

    mov eax, 1
    xor ebx, ebx
    int 80h
```

Then I tried to compile them and run:

```
[user ~/Documents/asm/callc]#make all
nasm main.asm -felf
gcc -c foo.c -o foo.o -m32
ld -o main main.o foo.o -melf_i386 -lc
[user ~/Documents/asm/callc]#ls
foo.c  foo.o  main  main.asm  main.o  Makefile
[user ~/Documents/asm/callc]#./main 
bash: ./main: No such file or directory
[user ~/Documents/asm/callc]#bash main
main: main: cannot execute binary file
```

I didn't get any errors but apparently I couldn't run the executable output file.

If the c function doesn't call any library functions then the code above can be compiled and it will run without any problems. I also figured out a way to call library functions directly in nasm and use gcc to produce the final executable file. But none of them is exactly what I want.

**EDIT:**
1. I'm running 64-bit Ubuntu but I'm trying to write 32-bit programs so I used flags like -m32 and -melf_i386.
2. Output of `file *`:

```
[user ~/Documents/asm/sof]#file *
foo.c:     C source, ASCII text
foo.c~:    empty 
foo.o:     ELF 32-bit LSB  relocatable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
main:      ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
main.asm:  C source, ASCII text
main.asm~: empty 
main.o:    ELF 32-bit LSB  relocatable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
Makefile:  makefile script, ASCII text
Makefile~: makefile script, ASCII text
```

3. I really have no idea of how to tell ld to include the c standard library. I found something like -lglibc or -lc in some other posts. -lgibc doesn't work and -lc seems to be able to get rid of all errors and I probably thought it worked at first but maybe that's the problem since it probably doesn't link the correct library.

**UPDATE**
Adding `-I/lib32/ld-linux.so.2` to the `ld` command solved my problem.
Below are commands to compile/assemble/link and run the program:

```
nasm main.asm -felf
gcc -c foo.c -o foo.o -m32
ld -o main main.o foo.o -melf_i386 -lc -I/lib32/ld-linux.so.2
./main
```

Comment: Are you on a 32 or 64 bit Linux system? Run `file *` in that directory, and edit your answer to include the output.  Also, although this isn't causing your problem of an invalid executable, you shouldn't expect to call C standard library functions if the C runtime code didn't run first.

Comment: Aside:  Why does the prompt look like you're compiling and running stuff as root?  :P

Comment: @cHao Why do you think so? You can customize the prompt however you want so pretty much it can be anything that can be displayed as text.

Comment: @uNiverselEgacy: The `#` in the prompt customarily means the shell is running as root.  For non-root users, it's usually `$`.  There's an escape sequence (`\$`) to display the one that's correct, so either you're running as root, or you've configured the shell to lie.  :)

Comment: @cHao Thanks for the info. I didn't really notice this before. But I don't really like to have a `$` in the prompt so I just configured it to always display `#`.

Comment: On the whole, I think you're best off not creating `_start` in your assembler code.  You might create `main` as the start point.  If you create `_start`, you're missing all the normal support code that sorts things out before `main` is called; little things such as 'loading the standard C shared library' etc.

Comment: I'd echo @cHao's comment about the prompt — don't give the impression of programming as root (or, if you do, expect to be called on it every time).  I don't particularly like `$` in the prompt either, so my prompt is normally `Machine JL: ` (the host name, my initials, and a colon-space).  But when I answer (or ask) questions on SO, I usually use `$ ` as the prompt, editing what I got on my screen so it matches that.

Comment: LD needs a special loader: `ld -o main main.o foo.o -melf_i386 -lc -I/lib32/ld-linux.so.2`

Comment: @rkhb: It worked! But from some of the comments above and stuff I found online I've been told that some kind of init process has to run first before the standard c library can function. I disassembled the executable file and didn't seem to find code to do that. So I'm not sure why this works or what I've been told is not necessarily true.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I was able to [use `_start` and make standard libraries calls fine using dynamic linkage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26358119/static-linkage-with-glibc-without-calling-main). However, I did not manage to do this with static linkage.

Answer (score 4):

The C library provides code using the _start interface that starts the C runtime, calls main(), and shuts the runtime down. Hence if you intend to use the C library in your program you must not use the _start interface but provide a main() function.

This is the correct way to do it:

```
; main.asm
global main
extern foo

section .text
main:
    push 1234567
    call foo
    add esp, 4

    xor eax, eax
    ret
```

Build with:

```
nasm -f elf32 -o main.o main.asm
gcc -m32 -o foo.o -c foo.c
gcc -m32 -o main main.o foo.o
```

Two remarks:

- main() returns, instead of doing an exit system call, to allow the C runtime shutdown code to run.
- gcc is used for linking. Internally gcc invokes ld with the appropriate parameters to link with the C library. These are platform specific and subject to change. Hence, don't use ld for this.