# Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses. NASM

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64, nasm

When I use `nasm -f macho64 asm1.asm` I get the following error:

> asm1.asm:14: error: Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses

This is `asm1.asm`

```
SECTION .data           ;initialized data

msg: db "Hello world, this is assembly", 10, 0

SECTION .text           ;asm code

extern printf
global _main

_main:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp

    push msg
    call printf

    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    ret
```

I'm really new to assembly and barely know what these commands do. Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis, but that answer does not really explain why `macho64` does not allow 32-bit absolute addressing. 32-bit absolute addressing works fine with elf64.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis, I moved my answer to the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091987/x64-nasm-pushing-memory-addresses-onto-the-stack-call-function/13092703?noredirect=1#comment41463350_13092703. This question is now a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mac OS X, like other UNIX/POSIX systems, uses a different calling convention for 64-bit code. Instead of pushing all the arguments to the stack, it uses `RDI`, `RSI`, `RDX`, `RCX`, `R8`, and `R9` for the first 6 arguments. So instead of using `push msg`, you'll need to use something like `mov RDI, msg`.

Comment: For reference, the related [section](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/LowLevelABI/140-x86-64_Function_Calling_Conventions/x86_64.html) of Mac Dev Library, and the [updated ABI](http://x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf).

Comment: Could you provide an example of a working version of the original program for educational purposes!

Comment: Or even better, **use `lea rdi, [rel msg]`** instead of a 10-byte `mov r64, imm64` with the 64-bit absolute address.  RIP-relative LEA is smaller and more efficient, and is position-independent so it doesn't need a fixup if the OS wants to use ASLR on the executable.

Answer (score -1):

Besides what Drew McGowen points out, `rax` needs to be zeroed (no vector parameters).

But `-f win64` or `-f elf64` will work on this code. I suspect a bug in `-f macho64` (but I'm not sure what `macho64` is "supposed" to do). Until this gets fixed(?), the workaround is to use `default rel` or `mov rdi, rel msg`. I "think" that'll work for ya.

Comment: This is not a NASM bug, `push` does not support 64-bit immediate values, per the [documentation](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.pdf).

Comment: True enough, but why does Nasm think it's a 32-bit address?

Comment: It's not a bug, it just does not support 32-bit absolute addressing. The image base is large than 2^32 by default on OS X.  See my answer.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis, no it's not a bug in NASM, it's a limitation of OS X. On Linux it would be a 32-bit address because the image base is < 2^32 on Linux.

Comment: `mov rdi, rel msg` is meaningless.  The RIP-relative way to get a symbol address into a register is `lea rsi, [rel msg]`.  `mov` is only available with a 32 or 64-bit immediate operand, not a `rel32`.  If `mov` works, then it's because NASM decided to use a 64-bit absolute immediate, which you don't want; RIP-relative `lea` is smaller and more efficient.