# Illegal instruction: 4 (Mac 64-bit, NASM)

Tags: macos, assembly, nasm, x86-64, ld

I'm trying to write a simple helloworld in assembler 64 on Mac with NASM.
Every time I try to run it I'm getting this error:

```
Illegal instruction: 4
```

Here is my code:

```
section .text
global _main

_main:
    mov rax, 4
    mov rbx, 1
    mov rcx, tekst
    mov rdx, dlugosc
    int 80h

    mov rax, 1
    int 80h

section .data

tekst   db  "Hello, world", 0ah
dlugosc equ $ - tekst
```

I'm compiling with:

```
nasm -f macho64 HelloWorld.asm
```

And I'm linking with:

```
ld -o HelloWorld -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.10 -lSystem -no_pie HelloWorld.o
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Try running it under the debugger.

Comment: `-macosx_version_min` and `10.10` should have an `=` in between, right?

Comment: If [this page](https://filippo.io/making-system-calls-from-assembly-in-mac-os-x/) is to be believed, you're using the wrong syscall numbers and putting your arguments in the wrong registers.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I disassembled the compiled version and it seems something changed all the 64 bit registers (rax, rbx) to 32 bit registers (eax, ebx) except for rcx.

Comment: @harold No, there shouldn't be "=" between.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Do you have any ideas on how to fix it then?

Comment: Did you read the linked page? It looks like a tutorial for exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Thank you so much. Didn't see the link before. The only thing I needed to change to make the code from the linked page work was to change all the "start" to "_main".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091987/x64-nasm-pushing-memory-addresses-onto-the-stack-call-function/26407526#26407526

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with the most important thing:

On Mac OSX, system calls are preceded by an 0x2000###, so for an exit it would 0x2000001.

Next, we need to use the correct registers to pass arguments.

```
The number of the syscall has to be passed in register rax.

rdi - used to pass 1st argument to functions
rsi - used to pass 2nd argument to functions
rdx - used to pass 3rd argument to functions
rcx - used to pass 4th argument to functions
r8 - used to pass 5th argument to functions
r9 - used to pass 6th argument to functions

A system-call is done via the syscall instruction. The kernel destroys registers rcx and r11.
```

So bringing this together, a fixed version of your code is:

```
section .text
global _main

_main:
    mov rax, 0x2000004
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, tekst
    mov rdx, dlugosc
    syscall

    mov rax, 0x2000001
    syscall

section .data

tekst   db  "Hello, world", 0ah
dlugosc equ $ - tekst
```